# Magento2: How to apply cart rules by condition?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

I have accessories category products. If I add only accessories category product in the cart then apply to no free shipping for accessories category products. If I add accessories category product and also add with other category product rules apply to free shipping.

Can you tell me how to add condition above method?

[image]

Comment: share the screen-sort of rule condition what you have try?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya https://ibb.co/j1p47U

Comment: @DhirenVasoya got the message?

Comment: let me know if you still looking for the solution ?

Comment: @AdityaShah my issue is resolved